# Remove domain/tenant or close account in Microsoft Partner Center & Azure AD portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I created a corporate developer account in [Microsoft Partner Center](https://partner.microsoft.com/), and verified domain. But I didn't go through all the other corporate verification steps. Now I wonder how could I remove the domain from Microsoft Partner Center, or close this account (I am the owner).

[image]

It seems that the "Remove" (not clickable) is a text not a button in the screenshot.

Also when I login to azure portal, and follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto) to delete Azure AD directory, the "Delete directory" button is greyed out (not clickable). The weird thing is that my role is User. Should I be administrator since I am Owner in Partner Center? Who will be admin if my role is "User" since I have only one account. Is there a way to delete the tenant?

Comment: Do you know how did you create the Azure AD directory?

Comment: No, I didn't create it on purpose. I guess it is auto created.